# determining the height of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

After setting the height of some element (say a div) to auto, still can I get the height of this div in pixel or may be in some other units

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight) or [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight).

Or if jQuery is a choice, something like:

```
$("#element").height();
```