# how to get the height of a element including padding and borders using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i would like to know how to get the height of a element including padding and borders using javascript so ill know the actually height the element has when rendered in a browser.
Can anyone help me please and im still new to javascript

Comment: Hi, your question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777897/determining-the-height-of-an-element

Comment: happens not the first time :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're looking for [`element.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) and [`element.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth).

[According to quirksmode.com](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t34), these properties work in all of the major browsers. Hooray!

Answer (score 9):

Using jQuery, you can get element height including padding with
`$(ele).outerHeight()`,
get element height including padding, border and margin by
`$(ele).outerHeight(true)`.

see also https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/